# Airflow Dag starts immediately

Tags: airflow

I have a question please,below the parameters of my airflow  diagram

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'me',
'email': ['tig.bena@gmail.com',"tig.bena@yahoo.com"],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'start_date': dt.datetime(2024, 3, 4, 9, 55, 00),

}
```

I launch airflow with docker compose, the problem is that my diagram is launched directly when I launch docker-compose up
although the launch date is 2024
any idea please ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow may launch a DAG immediately even if the start date is in the future because of a feature called "catchup" mode. When "catchup" mode is enabled, Airflow will run all the tasks for all the past instances of a DAG Run, up to the current date and time.

This feature is usually used to quickly bring a DAG up-to-date after it has been turned off or if it has missed some runs. You can control the behavior of "catchup" mode in the DAG configuration by setting the "catchup" parameter to either "True" or "False".

`If you set it to "catchup": "False", Airflow will only run the tasks for the future instances of a DAG Run and will not run any tasks for past instances.`